# Removing column in R that meets certain criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I want to remove columns from a Dataframe where the ratio of zero values to non zero values is above certain threshold say 0.4.
The code I wrote to perform the same operation is as follows

```
ZeroValRatio <- as.data.frame(colSums(train1==0)/nrow(train1))

ZeroValRatio <- rename(zeroValRatio,value="colSums(train1 == 0)/nrow(train1)")

drop <- as.data.frame(filter(ZeroValRatio,value>"0.3198630137"))

drop <-as.data.frame(t(drop))

df <- subset(train1,select = -which(colnames(drop)==colnames(train1)))
```

here,
train1 = the original dataframe on which I want to perform the operation.

After running this code the final dataframe "df" still had 4 variables in the drop.
Moreover after running the code

```
df2 = train1[,!(names(train1) %in% drop)]
```

I got df2 with all the columns in train1 without actually performing the dropping operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can select patients from your dataframe who meet the condition for each column.
Here is a code that simulate data and select the specific columns.

```
#1- Simulating dataset
set.seed(1)
df1=data.frame(X1=sample(c(0,1),40,TRUE),X2=sample(c(0,1),40,TRUE),X3=sample(c(0,1),40,TRUE),X4=sample(c(0,1),40,TRUE))

#2- Checking which columns should be removed (i.e. proportion>=0.40)
apply(df1,2,function(x) sum(x==0)/length(x))

#3- Keeping only columns with the condition from df1 to df2
df2=df1[,which(apply(df1,2,function(x) sum(x==0)/length(x))>=0.40)]

#4- Verification
apply(df2,2,function(x) sum(x==0)/length(x))
```